# cannot retreive data from a prepopulated sqlite database in dot net maui for andriod

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, maui

I am creating a dot net maui android app. The app needs to access a prepopulated sqlite data base and retrieve a list of questions. I have the database and I seem to be linking it correctly to the application but I cannot retrieve the data.

This is how i am asking for the data :

```
 private async Task<List<TodoItem>> RetrieveFromDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            var compDatabase = new CompDatabase();
            var questions = await compDatabase.GetItemsAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Lines retrieved: " + questions.Count);
            return questions;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving questions: " + ex.Message);
            // Handle any exceptions here
            return new List<TodoItem>();
        }
    }
```

[DOTNET] Lines retrieved: 0

the below is based on the micros soft example : https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/Data/TodoSQLite/TodoSQLite/Data/TodoItemDatabase.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;
using Comp.Models;

namespace Comp.Data
{
    public class CompDatabase
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

        public CompDatabase()
        {
        }

        async Task Init()
        {
            if (Database is not null)
                return;

            Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
            var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>();
        }

        public async Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            await Init();

            Console.WriteLine("Database path: " + Constants.DatabasePath);
            Console.WriteLine("Database file exists: " + File.Exists(Constants.DatabasePath));


            return await Database.Table<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
        {
            await Init();
            return await Database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(t => t.IsAnsweredCorrectly).ToListAsync();

            // SQL queries are also possible
            //return await Database.QueryAsync<TodoItem>("SELECT * FROM [TodoItem] WHERE [Done] = 0");
        }

        public async Task<TodoItem> GetItemAsync(int id)
        {
            await Init();
            return await Database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public async Task<int> SaveItemAsync(TodoItem item)
        {
            await Init();
            if (item.ID != 0)
            {
                return await Database.UpdateAsync(item);
            }
            else
            {
                return await Database.InsertAsync(item);
            }
        }

        public async Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(TodoItem item)
        {
            await Init();
            return await Database.DeleteAsync(item);
        }

    }
}
```

[DOTNET] Database path: /data/user/0/com.companyname.comp/files/Databases/TodoSQLite.db3

[DOTNET] Database file exists: True

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;

namespace Comp.Databases
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string DatabaseFilename = "TodoSQLite.db3";

        public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;


        public static string DatabasePath
        {
            get
            {
                var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
                return Path.Combine(basePath, "Databases", DatabaseFilename); // Make sure the path includes "Databases" folder
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont understand and cant seem to find the reason as to why I cannot retrieve the data.
according to my Console logs the data base is being passed to the android emulator so it should be accessible and i am not getting any errors.

Comment: How are you creating the db and adding it to your project?

Comment: `the data base is being passed to the android emulator` What exactly is happening? I you have a prepopulated database file then what did you do to copy it to the path your app is expecting? Which path?

Comment: `"Databases" the name of the folder is "databases".

Comment: created the database and populated data using DB Browser for SQLite.
added the database by copying to the project and "add existing item"

Comment: And after that where would it land in your project? And if it is in your project on pc  then how would it land in the databases directory of your apps private dir in emulator or device?

Comment: @blackapps I have the database "TodoSQLite.db3" in my Databases folder. 
for the database i have the build action set as Android Asset, do not copy.
from what I know (read/watched) the database should be complied with the app. Is this not correct ?

Comment: if it is an Android asset then you will need to read it with AssetManager and copy it to the destination folder when your app starts.  Files are not automatically copied to `LocalApplicationData`

Comment: `[DOTNET] Database file exists: True` Please elaborate.

Comment: `new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path)` will **create** an empty db if one does not already exist at `path`

Comment: Indeed. And then it has to be overwritten with the one from assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SQLConnection>(s => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<SQLConnection>(s));

        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Neminaj.Resources.Database.test.db3"))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                File.WriteAllBytes(SQLConnection.m_DBPath, memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

**SQLConnection.cs**

```
public class SQLConnection
{
    public static string m_DBPath { get; } = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "test.db3");
    public static SQLiteAsyncConnection m_ConnectionAsync = null;
    public static SQLiteConnection m_ConnectionSync = null;

    public static string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    public SQLConnection()
    {
        InitAsync(); // todo
    }

    public static async Task InitAsync()
    {
        if (m_ConnectionAsync is not null)
            return;

        m_ConnectionAsync = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLConnection.m_DBPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);

        await m_ConnectionAsync.CreateTableAsync<Test>();
        await m_ConnectionAsync.CreateTableAsync<TestTable>();
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you !!.   
You helped point me in the right direction.  I found my answer with "Gerald Versluis : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftDq-leq5OM : https://github.com/jfversluis/ExistingSQLiteDbSample/tree/main"